# (r-1)-partition of a balanced complete r-partite graph

Tags: combinatorics

Let $G=K_{m,\ldots,m}$ be a complete $r$-partite graph. How to show that for any $(r-1)$-partition $V_1, \ldots, V_{r-1}$ of $V(G)$, the number of edges within a part is at least $m^2$ (i.e., $\sum_{1\leq i\leq r-1}e_G(V_i)\geq m^2$)?

If we consider a $k$-partition for certain $k\leq r-1$, what can we get?

Comment: If you take $r = 2$, for each triangle, there is at least one edge in some part. Can you do something about it ? Does it generalizes ? (be careful, the line of argument may not be as obvious as it seems).

Comment: Each $K_r$ has at least one edge in some part, and each edge is contained in $m^{r-2}$ copies of $K_r$.

Comment: Yes, have you managed to get a full proof?

Comment: @caduk Yes, thank you very much for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I will put the answer:

Let $V_1, ..., V_{r-1}$ be a partition of the vertices of $K_{m, ..., m}$
Each $K_r$ has at least one edge in some of the $V_i$. Because each edge belongs to exactly $m^{r-2}$ copies of a $K_r$ and that there is $m^r$ copies of a $K_r$ in total, we know that there is at least $\frac{m^r}{m^{r-2}} = m^2$ edges contained in the $V_i$.

The bound is tight $m$ gets big: Let $I_1,\dots, I_r$ be the $r$ maximal independent sets of $G$. Lets take $V_i = I_i$ for $i=1\dots r-2$ and $V_{r-1} = I_{r-1}\cup I_r$. The edges contained in the $V_i$ are all in $V_{r-1}$, and there is $m^2$ in total.

When $k\leq r-1$, given a $K_r$, the $k$-partition that minimize the number of edges in the $V_i$ is to spread equally the vertices in the $V_i$. If we write $r = pk+q$ the euclidean division of $r$ by $k$, we get at least $(k-p)\binom{q}{2} + p\binom{q+1}{2}$ edges in the $V_i$. By considering all the $K_r$, we get that at least $m^2\left((k-p)\binom{q}{2} + p\binom{q+1}{2}\right)$ edges are in the $V_i$.

This is tight: We put $q$ $I_i$ sets in $(k-p)$ $V_i$ and $q+1$ $I_i$ sets in $p$ $V_i$. The total number of edges matches the lower bound.